# How to export Azure diagnostics to Splunk

Tags: azure-functions, azure-monitoring

I have Functions, Web App, SQL Server etc and I need to export logs to Splunk.
What is best practise? Used resource diagnotics to store to blob then import to splunk?
Or should Azure monitor integrated to Splunk.

Answer (score -1):

One option is to use the [Azure Monitor Add-On for Splunk](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/3534/) directly.

If this is not possible, then you can first stream monitoring data to Event Hub and then send them to Splunk using this [Azure Function for Splunk](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureFunctionforSplunkVS) from there.

You can read more about streaming monitoring data to related products in this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/stream-monitoring-data-event-hubs).

Comment: You cannot output from an event hub to an Azure Function.

Comment: Technically, the Azure Function listens for events on the Event Hub. Not the other way around. Are you perhaps referring to something else here?